# $xy''+2y'+xy=0$ , given $y_1=\frac{sinx}{x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$xy''+2y'+xy=0$ , given $y_1=\frac{sinx}{x}$

How am I supposed to solve this ode?

Denote $y_2=z\cdot \frac{sinx}{x}$ , I got $y'$ and $y''$ extremely complicated.

I think I suppose to solve it using other methods.

I'll be grateful for help.

Thanks !

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3819694/solve-xy2yxy-1?noredirect=1

Comment: You get the solution in short form by observing that $(xy)''=xy''+2y'$. Here this is only useful to test the application of the demanded technique.

Answer (score 1):

$$xy_2''+2y_2'+xy_2=0$$
You can cheat a little bit to make things easier ( read @Lutz Lehmann 's comment  and the link provided in the first comment by  RamanujanXV ):
$$(xy_2)''+xy_3=0$$
$$(z \sin x)''+z \sin x=0$$
$$(z' \sin x + z \cos x)'+z \sin x=0$$
$$z'' \sin x +2z' \cos x -z \sin x + z \sin x =0$$
$$z'' \sin x +2z' \cos x =0$$
It's easy now to integrate. It's separable.
$$\int \dfrac {dz'}{z'}=- 2\int \dfrac {d \sin x}{\sin x}$$
$${z'}=\dfrac {C}{\sin^2 x}$$
$${z(x)}= {C_1}{\cot x}$$
$$y_2(x)=C_1 \dfrac {\cos x} x$$

Answer (score 0):

Given that the equation is $xy''(x)+2y'(x)+xy(x)=0,$ you can let $z(x)=xy(x),$ hence $z''(x)+z(x)=0,$ and so $z(x)=C_0\cos(x)+C_1\sin(x).$ Therefore, $$y(x)=C_0\frac{\cos(x)}{x}+C_1\frac{\sin(x)}{x}.$$

This is cheating, though, because I know this is not what your professors intend for you to do. So instead, here is what you should do: let $y_0=Qy_1,$ where $Q'\neq0.$ $y_0'=Q'y_1+Qy_1',$ and $y_0''=Q''y_1+2Q'y_1'+Qy_1''.$ Hence $$xy_0''(x)+2y_0'(x)+xy_0(x)=Q(x)[xy_1''(x)+2y_1'(x)+xy_1(x)]+x[Q''(x)y_1(x)+2Q'(x)y_1'(x)]+2Q'(x)y_1(x)=0=x[Q''(x)y_1(x)+2Q'(x)y_1'(x)]+2Q'(x)y_1(x)=xy_1(x)Q''(x)+[2xy_1'(x)+2y_1(x)]Q'(x).$$ $xy_1(x)=\sin(x)$ and $$2xy_1'(x)+2y_1(x)=2x\frac{x\cos(x)-\sin(x)}{x^2}+2\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=2\cos(x),$$ hence $\sin(x)Q''(x)+2\cos(x)Q'(x)=0.$ Let $Q'(x)=P(x),$ hence $\sin(x)P'(x)+2\cos(x)P(x)=0,$ which is equivalent to $P(x)=0$ or $$\frac{P'(x)}{P(x)}=-2\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)},$$ which is equivalent to $$\ln[(-1)^nP(x)]=\begin{cases}-2\ln[|\sin(x)|]+A_m&m\in(m\pi,(m+1)\pi)\end{cases},$$ for $n\in\{0,1\},$ the latter of which is equivalent to $$P(x)=\begin{cases}(-1)^ne^{A_m}\frac1{\sin(x)^2}&m\in(m\pi,(m+1)\pi)\end{cases}$$ $$=\begin{cases}B_p\frac1{\sin(x)^2}&m\in(m\pi,(m+1)\pi)&x\in[p\pi,(p+1)\pi]\end{cases}=Q'(x),$$ suggesting $$Q(x)=\begin{cases}-B_p\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}&m\in(m\pi,(m+1)\pi)&x\in[p\pi,(p+1)\pi]\end{cases}=\begin{cases}C_p\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}&m\in(m\pi,(m+1)\pi)&x\in[p\pi,(p+1)\pi]\end{cases}$$ and thus $$y_0(x)=C_p\frac{\cos(x)}{x}.$$